# Creating a small wiggle from a shake on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building my first site and really wanted a button which wiggled. I was doing some research and i found the perfect button that i want.

[Link](https://elrumordelaluz.github.io/csshake/)

If you scroll down to the end of the page. The way the download button looks is exactly what i wanted. However for some reason i been playing around with the code and i dont get any sort of animation to appear. No idea why this is. If possible could someone show me the way on how to code this? 
Thanks

Sorry forgot the code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
    }
}

.wiggle:hover {
    -webkit-animation: wiggle 0.5s infinite;
}
```

This is not from the site, this is my trying , but it does not get the right effect which is the same as the download button. I am actually really stuck on this hahaha :) So any help on this would be great x

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/a0ddh7un/1/ (assuming you are in a webkit browser). If you are using a non-webkit browser you need to create a non-prefixed version. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome. I dunno. Also i am trying to add the box around it etc and just wont do it at all, i will keep trying, also however this is not the affect i wanted, on the link if you scroll down you can see the download button there moves different to the one i did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check their animations from here https://elrumordelaluz.github.io/csshake/css/csshake.css to get a clue.

Comment: Ah i haev but i am not sure which on is for the download one, could you point me in the right direction and link me the download code

Comment: search for the below classes inside their stylesheets :
btn 
carrot 
shake-vertical-slow 
shake-constant 
shake-constant--hover

Comment: Ya this is what i have done but i cant seem to find that class in the code

Comment: Thank you :) i am still going with it but just struggling really bad for some reason :)

Comment: OK, what they suggest here is to embed their stylesheet and add a specific class for each animation you want. For example the animation you want has the class "shake-slow shake-constant shake-constant--hover" . Check here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yfwmsjdf/) my example

Comment: Perfect answer thanks so much for all the help :) xxx